# Unable to retrieve contents of Chrome Console using Selenium Webdriver in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to read the Chrome console using Selenium Webdriver in node.js, but so far it is unsuccessful. There are no errors. But all it returns is an empty array [].

The following is a snippet of the HTML and JavaScript function. When run manually in Chrome, these write to the console just fine.

```
<button name="button1" type="button" onclick="test_console()">Test</button>

function test_console() {
    console.log("Hello World");
}
```

The following is the code I am using in node.js to try to get the output to Chrome.

```
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
const chromeDriver = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
const logging = require('selenium-webdriver').logging;
const path = require('chromeDriver').path;

const service = new chromeDriver.ServiceBuilder(path).build();
chromeDriver.setDefaultService(service);

const {By, Key} = webdriver;

webdriver.promise.USE_PROMISE_MANAGER = false;

const CHROME_BIN_PATH = '/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome';

const prefs = new logging.Preferences();
prefs.setLevel(logging.Type.BROWSER, logging.Level.ALL);

const options = new chromeDriver.Options();
options.setChromeBinaryPath(CHROME_BIN_PATH);
options.addArguments(
    'headless',
    'disable-gpu',
    'verbose',
    'disable-impl-side-painting',
);

const main = async () => {
    try {

    const driver = await new webdriver.Builder()
        .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome())
        .setLoggingPrefs(prefs)
        .forBrowser('chrome')
        .setChromeOptions(options)
        .build();

    await driver.get('http://example.com/example.html');

    //clicking this button manually in Chrome writes to the console
    await driver.findElement(By.name('button1')).click();

    await driver.manage().logs().get(logging.Type.BROWSER)
    .then(function(entries) {
        console.log(entries);
    });

    await driver.close();
    await driver.quit();

    } catch (error) {
        await driver.close();
        await driver.quit();
        console.log(error);
    }
};

main();
```

I'm sure the issue is simple, probably a configuration problem. I just cant figure out what the problem might be. I even resorted to reading the webdriver source code in Git to see if I could see anything, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, getting the contents of the console from Chrome using webdriver is a no go.

I ended up solving the issue in this manner:

```
//append a div to the body of the page
await driver.executeScript("var div = document.createElement('div'); div.id = 'console_log'; document.body.appendChild(div);");

//override console.log to write the log message to the new div          
await driver.executeScript("console.log = function(message){document.getElementById('console_log').innerHTML += message}");

//get the contents of the new div
const console_log = await driver.findElement(By.id('console_log'));
console.log(await console_log.getAttribute('innerHTML'));
```